# Fourier transform of the form subtraction of two exponential functions by addition of two exponential functions

Tags: fourier-transform

How to find the fourier sine and cosine transform of :

$$\frac{e^{ax}+e^{-ax}}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}$$

Comments:

I found out partial derivative of the transform w.r.t $a$ and $b$ (I generalized the denominator as $b$ instead of $\pi$).

Also, i tried to compute the transform using integration by parts with the given function as the first function and $cos(\alpha x)$ as the second function.

Then, i could rewrite the transform $I$ as

$$a\frac{\partial I}{\partial a} + b\frac{\partial I}{\partial b} - 
\alpha\frac{\partial I}{\partial \alpha} = I + \frac{2}{b}$$

By far i only know solving partial differential equations (PDEs) in two variables. This PDE appears to be simple but i can't solve it as of now.

Comment: If this Fourier Transform even exists, you'll likely have to use contour integration in the complex plane to find its Cauchy Principle Value.  For $a=b$ this function is $\mathrm{coth}(ax)$ which has a singularity at 0.  This function is strictly odd, so the Fourier Cosine Transform should be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform of $\operatorname{csch} \pi x$ (understood in the p.v. sense) can be found in the same way as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2977022), giving
$$F(w) = \mathcal F[\operatorname{csch} \pi x] = i \tanh \frac w 2.$$
Then, since the Fourier integral and $\tanh(w/2)$ are analytic in the strip $-\pi < \operatorname{Im} w < \pi$,
$$\frac 1 2 \mathcal F[(e^{a x} + e^{-a x}) \operatorname{csch} \pi x] =
\frac 1 2 (F(w - i a) + F(w + i a)) = \\
\frac {i \sinh w} {\cosh w + \cos a}, \quad -\pi < a < \pi.$$